# No output due to large fractional values

Tags: c++, double

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
float san= 0.25 ; float var= 0.75;
int findFact(int n)//factorial
{
    return n == 1 ? 1 : n * findFact(n - 1);
}
int findNcR(int n, int r)//combination nCr
{
    return findFact(n) / (findFact(n - r) * findFact(r));
}
double prob(int s, int v){ //recursive function for probability
 if(s>=5) return 1; if(v>=5) return 0;
 double sum = 0;
 int m = 5-s;
 for( int i=0; i<=m; i++){
     sum += prob(s+i,v+m-i)*findNcR(m,i)*pow(san,i)*pow(var,m-i);
 }
 return sum;
}
int main(){
    cout<< prob(2,1);
}
```

In DEV C++, there is no output printed when I compile and run the above code. I think its because of large fractional values involved. Any idea how I can get the output?

Comment: i think it is because of infinite recursion. Are you sure `prob(2,1)` does return?

Comment: `n!/(n-r)!` can be "simplified" to `(n-r+1) * (n-r+2) * .. * n`, so you don't compute `n!`

Comment: factorials are ok for analytic expressions. When actually computing some formula, most of the time you dont need the whole factorial because often most of it cancels out as suggested by Jarod42

Comment: Add the line `cout << s << ',' << v << endl;` first in `prob` so you can see where it goes.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed the base case to v>=5 and s>=5. But I still can't get an output.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logic you use in your `double prob(int s, int v)` method.
You are going to infinity recursive like

> S=2 V=1
> S=2 V=4
> S=2 V=7

Answer (score 0):

The base case for your recursion, `s==5` or `v==5` is never getting hit. As you call your function with `s=2`, every time the `prob` function is called it is setting `m` to `3`, and so on the first iteration of the loop (when `i==0`) it calls `prob` with `s=2` and `v=v+3`. As you start with `v==1`, it successively calls `prob(2,1)`, `prob(2,4)`, `prob(2,7)`, etc... and never gets any further.

I don't know what probability distribution you are trying to code so I can't offer any specific advice on how to fix this.